# Connecting to Redshift via PySpark, how do we get drivers to work?

Tags: python, pyspark, amazon-redshift, driver, databricks

I was trying to connect to Redshift using Pyspark and I would get the `Failed to find data source: com.databricks.spark.redshift` error. I was able to finally get rid of that error by manually calling all the drivers, but now I get a new error. What should I be doing differently?

Here is my code:

```py
import findspark
findspark.init()

from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

jars = ["C:\\Users\\vpena\\Documents\\spark\\spark-redshift_2.11-3.0.0-preview1.jar",
        "C:\\Users\\vpena\\Documents\\spark\\RedshiftJDBC42-no-awssdk-1.2.45.1069.jar",
        "C:\\Users\\vpena\\Documents\\spark\\minimal-json-0.9.4.jar",
        "C:\\Users\\vpena\\Documents\\spark\\spark-avro_2.11-3.0.0.jar"
       ]

ss = SparkSession.builder.config("spark.jars",  ",".join(jars)).getOrCreate()
sc = ss.sparkContext
sql_context = SQLContext(sc)



df = sql_context.read \
    .format("com.databricks.spark.redshift") \
    .option("url", f"jdbc:redshift://{keys['host']}:5439/{keys['database']}?user={keys['username']}&password={keys['password']}") \
    .option("query", "SELECT * FROM data_science_lab.iap_cube_user") \
    .option("tempdir", f"s3n://{keys_boto3['aws_access_key_id']}:{keys_boto3['aws_secret_access_key']}@{bucket_name}/tempvpena") \
    .load()
```

The new error I am getting is:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<timed exec> in <module>

~\Documents\spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py in load(self, path, format, schema, **options)
    182             return self._df(self._jreader.load(self._spark._sc._jvm.PythonUtils.toSeq(path)))
    183         else:
--> 184             return self._df(self._jreader.load())
    185 
    186     @since(1.4)

~\Documents\spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1304         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 
   1307         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~\Documents\spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    129     def deco(*a, **kw):
    130         try:
--> 131             return f(*a, **kw)
    132         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    133             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~\Documents\spark\spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.load.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.Parameters$MergedParameters.<init>(Parameters.scala:89)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.Parameters$.mergeParameters(Parameters.scala:83)
    at com.databricks.spark.redshift.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:50)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:339)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:279)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$2(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:268)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:203)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Is this the correct way to read data from Redshift to Pyspark? I've read [this](https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift) documentation but it's not too helpful.

Additional info: I am trying to run this code from a Jupyter Notebook and I got the drivers from [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/powering-amazon-redshift-analytics-with-apache-spark-and-amazon-machine-learning/).

Comment: What is your spark version?

Comment: Spark Version 3.0.0

Comment: @the_dummy what version of pyspark did you install? On windows, you can check with `pip freeze | findstr pyspark` This could be an issue with version mismatch

Comment: @NagarajTantri strangely enough, pyspark is not listed in pip freeze. But I know I have it, I've been using it... this is the first issue I have with it.

Comment: @the_dummy Are you using a virtualenv? What if you again try to do `pip install pyspark --upgrade` ?

Comment: As @NagarajTantri says I bet it is an environment issue. Assuming you are using Anaconda, please show what your environments page looks like from the Anaconda Navigator. If you only have "base", I would recommend creating a new one like I have here https://www.screencast.com/t/zu2SZlSyP

Answer (score 1):

As I can see, you are using `spark-3.0.0` which comes with `scala 2.12` but this `com.databricks.spark.redshift` package does not support that.

As I can see on this package's github page: https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift
,the last commit is from 2017. I would suggest you to move to a different package.

You can checkout this: https://github.com/spark-redshift-community/spark-redshift for spark versions greater than 3.0.

---

*I know this is an old post but writing this to help new users who might be facing the same issue.*

Answer (score 0):

Did you manage to resolve it?

https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
Note that, Spark 2.x is pre-built with Scala 2.11 except version 2.4.2, which is pre-built with Scala 2.12. Spark 3.0+ is pre-built with Scala 2.12.

I tried with Spark 2.4.8 which comes with Scala 2.11 and it works.